# How did Cross and Dot signs come in vector multiplication?

Tags: physics

We use cross sign in vector multiplication that gives vector result and dot sign that gives scalar result.

But how did the dot sign come in scalar  product and the cross sign in vector product? It could also have happened that we used cross sign for scalar  product and dot sign for vector product.